# Get widget XY position after applying pos_hint

Tags: python, kivy

After positioning a widget (e.g. Scatter) using pos_hint, how do I get the current x, y position (pos) ?

e.g.

```
wid.pos = (250, 350)
print wid.pos  <----- # it print (200, 350). Correct.
wid.pos_hint = {'top':0.9, 'right':0.5}  # moved the widget to other position using pos_hint.
print wid.pos  <----- # it sill print (200, 350) eventhough the widget position has changed.
```

---

---

**EDIT**: example code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter

Builder.load_string(""" 
<Icon@Scatter>: 
    size_hint: .06, .08

    Image:
        size: root.size
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: True
""")

class Icon(Scatter):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.pos = (200, 200)
        self.move()
        super(Icon, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def move(self):
        print "BEFORE: "
        print self.pos      # print 200, 200
        self.pos_hint = {'top':0.9, 'right':0.5} # assume now Scatter has moved to x800 y500.
        print "AFTER: "
        print self.pos      # it still print 200, 200 :(


class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Icon()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GameApp().run()
```

Comment: You seem to be doing it correctly. What values are you expecting and are you getting? Take into account that when you are using the `top` and `right` properties, Kivy is going to use the `top` and `right` border of both: the parent of the `Scatter` and **the Scatter itself**. You might be expecting that you are assigning the positioning to the bottom-left corner, whereas you are actually assigning to the top-right corner by using `top` and `right`.

Comment: Also, according to what I just said and depending on the parent, the `size` property is very important. If the parent is a simple `Widget`, the `size` will be 100x100 (by default), and if, for example, is a FloatLayout it could be of the same size of the parent (because the default is `size_hint: 1,1`) so the returned positioning would be `(0,0)` (Not completely sure in this case. Maybe even negative values)

Comment: @toto_tico My question earlier is unclear. I had edited the code. On line-3 of the code, I had moved the widget using pos_hint (assumed the new widget position is now at x500 y600). So on line-4, I'm actually expecting it to print position (500,600) but it printed (250, 350).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Window (and the layout itself) is not refresh immediately after assigning values that are honoured by layouts (like `size_hint` or `pos_hint`). They are updated just after the window is refresh (until the method ends)

You basically can call the method [`do_layout`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html#kivy.uix.layout.Layout.do_layout) explicitly. The documentation said that "this method is called when a layout is needed, by a trigger". I have to say that I am not sure if calling it explicitly could cause some problems because this kind of use is not documented. It is working for me but be careful:

```
wid.pos = (250, 350)
print wid.pos  # it prints (200, 350). Correct.
wid.pos_hint = {'top':0.9, 'right':0.5} 
print wid.pos  # it sill print (200, 350) 
wid.do_layout()
print wid.pos  # it should work now
```

This is not necessary when you let the window refresh, i.e. after you can actually see that the `Scatter` (or any other `Widget`) has moved.

---

**EDIT**: corrected version of the code in the question

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string(""" 
<Icon>: 
    size_hint: .06, .08

    Image:
        size: root.size
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: True

<BaseLayout>:
    icon: _icon
    Icon:
        id: _icon
    Button: 
        text: "Press me"
        size_hint: .1,.05
        on_press: _icon.move()
""")

class Icon(Scatter):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.pos = (200, 200)
        super(Icon, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def move(self):
        print "BEFORE: "
        print self.pos      # print 200, 200
        self.pos_hint = {'top':0.9, 'right':0.5} # assume now Scatter has moved to x800 y500.
        self.parent.do_layout()
        print "AFTER: "
        print self.pos      # it still print 200, 200 :(


class BaseLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass


class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return BaseLayout()

if __name__ == '__m
ain__':
    GameApp().run()
```

Comment: Tried the do_layout() method, and the outcome is the same. Still not able to get the new position.

Comment: Also tried to place the code (wid.pos_hint = ...) as a new function and call it, but the widget position is still not updated.

Comment: I added the code that is working for me. If the code works for you, it might be something related with the context in which you are operating (the scatter's parent for example?).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Using your code example, I had added my code in the post to simulate my actual code. When I use do_layout(), it throw error. I guess it is because I'm not using any layout.

Comment: if your are not using any layout, you cannot use `size_hint`, neither `pos_hint`. Use a `FloatLayout` as a parent which is the one that works more similar to the default `Widget`

Comment: (As seen in my edited post) Without using any layout, the size_hint and pos_hint is working. The scatter do changes position and size.

Comment: As I'm required to use the feature of a Scatter instead of Floatlayout. Thus I tried using ScatterLayout instead of Scatter, and do_layout() still throws error. Might need to explore some other walkaround for this issue.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your code. the problem is that your parent is not even a `Widget`, it is the `App` itself. The parent of the `Scatter` (or any `Widget`) should be a layout. `pos_hint` and `size_hint` are just honoured by Layouts. I ll modify your code but the problem is that you took out the `FloatLayout` from mine.

Comment: Notice that I am also using `self.parent.do_layout()`. It is the parent the one responsible to organize the child. You cannot call `self.move()` on the `__init__` constructor because the parent hasn't been assigned yet.

Comment: I just found that `pos_hint` can also be used by `Window` ([Read here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint)). The `Window` the root screen that contains all the widgets but it is not a  `Layout` and, therefore, it doesn't have the method `do_layout`. `Window` is neither a `Widget`.